# ng-repeat with ng-selected

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I am trying to figure out how to generate list of option elements using ng-repeat, but one of them to be marked as the selected option on load.

After googling, what I found is this base, which I modified by adding the selected property to the data objects
https://plnkr.co/edit/7g4MeAQnG4PzpnrebBGc?p=preview
However, it seems that `ng-selected="option.selected == true"` has no effect :(

Why? I also have the more complex example here: http://jsfiddle.net/ej5fx3kr/14/ which works, although I am not sure what is the difference, or what is the model here used for (note: changing the model name from "program" to anything, it still works... so not sure what is the purpose).

**Bonus points:** How do I debug code in AngularJS in directives? Like experiment in debug mode line by line to actually see what are the variable values in that particular scope, what is available to use, etc...

My ultimate goal in this question, is to load list of values via ajax on page load in the controller, IF there is a routeParam in the URL, find it in the list of loaded values, and add selected attribute, then set selected=true in the generated HTML on page load, otherwise not pre-select anything in the populated select box on the page load, so this is why its important for me to understand this on the simplest example before trying to plug this in.

Thanks!

Comment: the preferred way to handle this would be to use `ng-options` instead, and simply set the model equal to the default value on controller load.  I forked your plunker and added an example of this:  https://plnkr.co/edit/H520upiuJnBL6ESnKxk6?p=preview

Comment: @Claies Thanks!! This is so perfect and elegant :) Will play with it now :) If you can do an answer, will be happy to accept that as the best solution. No bonus points about the debugging question though! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "Angular Way" to handle this is to use `ng-options` instead of `ng-repeat`, and then simply set the model equal to the default value on controller load.

For example:

```
<select ng-options="option.name for option in data.availableOptions" 
        ng-model="selectedItem"></select>

$scope.selectedItem=$scope.data.availableOptions[2];
```

For a more advanced case, where your `ng-model` might not be the object in the array, but a single property, you can use a modified version of `ng-options`:

```
<select ng-options="option.id as option.name for option in data.availableOptions" 
        ng-model="selectedId"></select>

$scope.selectedId = '2';
```

Here is a modified version of your plunker showing these different possibilities:  https://plnkr.co/edit/xzYmXf8C3WuZaelwj5hO?p=preview

Comment: Thanks! While trying to replace the old one I had, I realized that we were using md-select (Material library) - and did a little investigation, its not straightforward to use this function inside md-select... But its a start for now I guess

Comment: I integrated it to my code, I still have two issues: 1) I had to do `ng-model="$scope.selectedId"`, otherwise it is not pre-selected. 2) the `<tt>id = {{selectedId}}</tt>` element is displaying the correct initial value, but it is not being updated when I change the selected value via UI. Why is that? If I change it to $scope prefix as well, it doesnt display even initial value.

Comment: that doesn't really make sense;  if you are using `$scope` in angular expressions (`ng-model`, `{{ }}`, etc.), then you have something else going on.

Answer (score 0):

Using `ng-selected = true`  inside `ng-repeat` would solve this .
However be sure of the data that you call in `ng-repeat`.For additional debugging and experiment line by line use chrome debugger .go to source tab and set break points on the js lines that you need to debug.This will let you debug line by line by pause and play . Hope this helps.Thanks

Comment: hmm how would you do that? ng-selected element inside ng-repeat... can you edit and show me what you mean?

Comment: debugging via Source tab in Chrome is what I do for normal JS for years. But here we are talking about AngularJS directives embedded in HTML, and as if that wasnt enough, they are in the PARTIAL html template files, so cant even see them in the (index) file of the Source tab...